# Continuity in Coma (2020 Russian film)

Tags: continuity, coma-2020

In the beginning of 2020 Russian film *Coma*, the main character, Victor a.k.a the Architect finds himself in a strange and magical world.

A soldier named Fly and some of her companions find him, save him from a bunch of black monsters and introduce this newbie to their leader Yan.

They tell him that they are in a coma world and everything they see is their past memories.

In the middle of the movie, Viktor suddenly gets out of coma and finds himself in a lab, then he remembers the reason he was comatose: He was driving with his wife (who is revealed to be Fly) to the house of a businessman to discuss his building designs in order to receive his investments. Viktor goes to the house alone. The businessman who is revealed to be Yan is actually an insane scientist who lures Viktor to the underground and manages to inject him with anaesthetics in order to render him comatose and research his brain just like his other victims (the soldiers in the coma world). But Viktor rushes out and manages to head back home with his wife. After a few minutes of driving they crash and their unconscious bodies are brought back to the lab to make them comatose. (Yan also always makes himself temporarily comatose to go to the coma world and speak to his patients who don't remember him.)

Yan who sees Viktor came out of coma makes him comatose again and Viktor decides to tell the soldiers about the real Yan in the coma world and also make Fly remember him.

**The Point**: Why was Fly in the coma world long before Victor if both of them became comatose nearly at the same time? As I said before, when Viktor became comatose for the first time he was found by Fly who was a soldier already and she introduced him to Yan and her other team.

P.S. Sorry if I explained too much and spoiled the film.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that was intended to be explained by the time dilation (which, admittedly, is kind of inconsistent in the film). In the time between when Fly was put into her coma, and Viktor followed, the time dilation stretched out that time for Fly, allowing her to establish herself, complicated by that the process seems to create a mixture of the person's original personality/memories, and those of their dream persona. So Fly could have been in that world for a longer amount of time, plus having "memories" of having been there even longer, when Viktor meets her.

Adding to that, I don't believe their entry in the world is based on when they actually became comatose (such as in the accident) so much as when Yan performs the procedure to put them into the shared dream.